# calculating all the the values of a flow in anylogic

Tags: sum, anylogic

I am writing an economic project in anylogic. I want to sum all the money that flows between two stocks, in fact I need to sum all the values that a flow get during simulation, till a specific condition, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com! It is expected to put some effort into solving a problem on your own, so please show what you've tried so far. Learn more on how stackoverflow works by taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
you need to be careful to understand how system dynamics works: it is a continuous process!

If you want to track your flows, the easiest option is to use a dataset object which tracks the flow at specific points in time.

Below, a flow "AdoptionRate" is tracked by dataset "AdoptersDS" every 0.1 minutes:
[image]

However, be aware that this tracks the flow at specific points in time. You can set up similar datasets for your stocks as well.

Alternatively, you could write a recurring event which stores the values at specific points in time into your build-in database.

Comment: it helped, but can I calculated integral of the figure form the DS?

Comment: I mean the  area under the figure of the data set.

Comment: I need it in order to calculated the sum of the all values in the Flow

Comment: there is no build-in function for datasets. You will need to loop across all its elements and sum them using Java.